# Плавная горизонтальная прокрутка по якорям внутри SVG

Tags: javascript, svg, прокрутка

Внутри блока с фиксированной шириной и горизонтальной прокруткой внутри него, находится длинный горизонтально ориентированный SVG-объект, внутри которого есть несколько элементов `rect` (разноцветные прямоугольники). Задача - организовать плавную прокрутку по якорям до начала каждого `rect`. Как вы можете видеть, прокрутка работает, но не плавно, и не до начала каждого цветного прямоугольника, а до непонятного места рядом с ним. В чем может быть проблема, и как ее решить? Спасибо!
UPD плавность я понимаю, можно наверно подключить какой-нибудь плагин типа smooth scroll, а что делать с тем, что переход по якорю не докручивает до нужного места?

```html
<div style="width:300px;"><a href="#s1">Слайд 1</a> <a href="#s2">Слайд 2</a> <a href="#s3">Слайд 3</a> <a href="#s4">Слайд 4</a> <a href="#s5">Слайд 5</a> <a href="#s6">Слайд 6</a><a href="#s7">Слайд 7</a> <a href="#s8">Слайд 9</a> <a href="#s9">Слайд 9</a>  </div>
<div style="width:300px;height:150px;overflow-x:scroll;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 250456.23 21872.12" style="height:150px;width:auto;">
  <rect id="s1" style="fill:black;" x="-0.01" y="0" width="18645.62" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s2" style="fill:red;" x="18645.64" y="0" width="34774.19" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s3" style="fill:yellow;" x="53419.8" y="0" width="34486.9" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s4" style="fill:magenta;" x="87906.72" y="0" width="17075.63" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s5" style="fill:blue;" x="104982.31" y="0" width="53953.27" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s6" style="fill:brown;" x="158935.6" y="0" width="21290.5" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s7" style="fill:lightblue;" x="180226.12" y="0" width="24489.01" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s8" style="fill:lightgreen;" x="204715.1" y="0" width="26714.08" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s9" style="fill:green;" x="231429.2" y="0" width="18735.64" height="21872.12"/> 
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Плавная прокрутка на css, добавь к элементу:

```
scroll-behavior: smooth;
```

якорь можно переписать на js `scrollTo()`, но в случае svg я быстрее сделал через scrollBy

```
document.getElementById('scrollwindow').scrollBy(
  document.getElementById('s2').getBoundingClientRect().x,
  0
)
```

полный код

```js
function ascroll(e) {
e.preventDefault();
let href = e.target.attributes.href.value
let rectid = href.slice(1)
document.getElementById('scrollwindow').scrollBy(
  document.getElementById(rectid).getBoundingClientRect().x,
  0
)

}
```

```html
<div style="width:300px;"><a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s1">Слайд 1</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s2">Слайд 2</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s3">Слайд 3</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s4">Слайд 4</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s5">Слайд 5</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s6">Слайд 6</a><a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s7">Слайд 7</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s8">Слайд 9</a> <a onclick="ascroll(event)" href="#s9">Слайд 9</a>  </div>

<div style="scroll-behavior: smooth;width:300px;height:150px;overflow-x:scroll;" id="scrollwindow">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 250456.23 21872.12" style="height:150px;width:auto;">
  <rect id="s1" style="fill:black;" x="-0.01" y="0" width="18645.62" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s2" style="fill:red;" x="18645.64" y="0" width="34774.19" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s3" style="fill:yellow;" x="53419.8" y="0" width="34486.9" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s4" style="fill:magenta;" x="87906.72" y="0" width="17075.63" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s5" style="fill:blue;" x="104982.31" y="0" width="53953.27" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s6" style="fill:brown;" x="158935.6" y="0" width="21290.5" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s7" style="fill:lightblue;" x="180226.12" y="0" width="24489.01" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s8" style="fill:lightgreen;" x="204715.1" y="0" width="26714.08" height="21872.12"/>
  <rect id="s9" style="fill:green;" x="231429.2" y="0" width="18735.64" height="21872.12"/> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Не силен в js, но scrollTo() как я понимаю использует конкретные координаты, на которые нужно прокручивать? Например, scrollTo(0,200)? Боюсь, в моем случае это решение не подойдет.

Comment: @Александр подойдет, только нужно найти координаты в Доме. Я тут потыкал инспектором в элемент и нашел относительные координаты. Пример добавил в ответ

Comment: @Александр добавил полный пример в ответ

Comment: спасибо большое, а еще подскажите пожалуйста, у меня блок, внутри которого находится SVG, имеет `position:fixed`, и `left:100px`, но слайд прокручивается до левого края экрана, а не левого края самого блока. Можно ли это исправить?

Comment: Тогда нужно сложить и вычесть смещение блока, смещение прокрутки и смещение слайда (посмотри свойство getClientRect() ещё) и использовать scrollTo